# How to remove brackets, quotes, and add a space after each comma for a const - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a `const` variable like so:

```
const result = _.map(daysOfWeek, function(value, key) {
      if (value == true) {
        value = ': Y';
      }
      else {
        value = ': N';
      }
      return key + value;
    });

console.log(result);
```

My code is reading in a json variable `daysOfWeek` that is formatted like:

```
"daysOfWeek": {
                "sunday": false,
                "monday": false,
                "tuesday": false,
                "wednesday": false,
                "thursday": false,
                "friday": false,
                "saturday": false
            },
```

and if the value is false, it is converting to an 'N' and if true, converting to a 'Y'.

The `console.log(result)` line is printing out the following line verbatim:

```
["sunday: Y","monday: Y","tuesday: Y","wednesday: Y","thursday: Y","friday: Y","saturday: Y"]
```

This is great, however I would like to get rid of the braces, double quotes, and add a space after the commas, and ideally, if possible capitalize the beginning of each day of the week, so that the end result looks like so:

```
Sunday: Y, Monday: Y, Tuesday: Y, Wednesday: Y, Thursday: Y, Friday: Y", Saturday: Y
```

I have tried some `regex` expressions like

```
console.log(result.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
```

and

```
alert(result);
alert(result.replace(/\"/g, ""));
```

but I can't seem to find a way to format this the way I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need or want a regular expression for this. What you're getting from `_.map` is an array of strings. To get the result you want:

1. In your map callback, do the capitalization of `key`.
2. Use `.join(", ")` on the resulting array to join all entries into one string using `", "` as the delimiter

You can also swap the `if`/`else` for the conditional operator if you like. Something like:

```
const result = _.map(daysOfWeek, function(value, key) {
    return key.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
           key.substring(1) + 
           ": " +
           (value ? "Y" : "N");
}).join(", ");
```

or with an arrow function and a template literal

```
const result = _.map(daysOfWeek, (value, key) =>
    `${key.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${key.substring(1)}: ${value ? "Y" : "N"}`
).join(", ");
```

or with iterable destructuring, an arrow function, and a template literal:

```
const result = _.map(daysOfWeek, (value, [first, ...rest]) =>
    `${first.toUpperCase()}${rest.join("")}: ${value ? "Y" : "N"}`
).join(", ");
```

though that involves a temporary array.

Comment: yes that makes perfect sense. Thank you, I was getting tunnel vision and your solution works perfectly!

Comment: @FranceMadrid - We've all done that! :-) Happy coding.